# Why can't I run two node.js AWS opsworks layers?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

This might be very simple to fix, but it seems that I cannot deploy two node.js OpsWorks layers on AWS. I need to have one layer for node.js for my web front-end, and I middle tier that consumes messages from a queue. I have the web node.js layer running, but now when I try to add a second node.js layer, node.js is not one of the options in the drop-down. Is this intentional? I've been forced to create a second app for my node.js layer to deal with this, but it is an ugly solution since by default the same chef scripts run on all the node.js instances and on my load balancing layer. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I can create a new stack for the second node.js layer, which is not ideal, but will work for now.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a second App is the best way to go.

In your recipes, you can use [stack configuration and deployment attribute values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/cookbooks-101-opsworks-opsworks-stack-config.html) to see in which layer the current instance resides, and decide what you should do (if anything) when a configure/deploy lifecycle event runs.

- On your front-end layer, you would deploy the frontend app and ignore
  the second app and vice versa on your middle tier layer.
- On your load balancer, you would probably do nothing on deploy.

To identify which app is being deployed in a Deploy life cycle event you can leverage the search function within chef and a "deploy" attribute placed on the application.

```
search(:aws_opsworks_app, "deploy:true").each do |app|
  #Your deploy logic here
end
```